# cost of atomic<int>::fetch_add verses __sync_fetch_and_add

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I was doing some research on g++ 4.4.6 on linux related to atomics. I had a simple loop that I was using to estimate the time it took to do a fetch_add(1) on an atomic.

```
atomic<int> ia;
ia.store(0);
timespec start,stop;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
while (ia < THE_MAX)
{
    //++ia;
    ia.fetch_add(1);
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
```

I was surprised to find that the following ran in about half the time:

```
volatile int ia=0;
timespec start,stop;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
while (ia < THE_MAX)
{
    __sync_fetch_and_add( &ia, 1 );
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
```

I disassembled it - not that I'm very good on x86 assembler - and I see this main difference. The C++11 atomics call generated

```
call    _ZNVSt9__atomic213__atomic_baseIiE9fetch_addEiSt12memory_order
```

whereas the gcc atomic gave

```
lock addl   $1, (%eax)
```

I would expect g++ to give me the best option, so I'm thinking there's some serious dropout in my understanding of what is going on. Is it clear to anyone out there why the C++ call didn't generate as good as the gcc atomic call? (Maybe it is just an issue of g++ 4.4 not being very mature...).
Thanks.

Comment: Try a more recent version of GCC...

Comment: Alas, I cannot for the moment. I think the maturity of g++ 4.4 was the issue.

Comment: You had optimizations on, right?

Comment: Yes (-O2). I didn't expect to miss an inline opportunity that way.

Comment: interestingly, i see that the member function for the atomic<int> is declared volatile. The member variable is just int. I'm not sure what volatile means in that context.

Comment: I guess it means to to treat the member variable (this) as volatile within that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of GCC version and optimizations. For example, with gcc 4.6.3 and -O3, I get a `lock add` for `atomic<int>::fetch_add`.

```
#include <atomic>
void j(std::atomic<int>& ia)
{
        ia.fetch_add(1);
}
```

Yields (for x86_64 with -O3 and gcc-4.6.3):

```
.LFB382:
    .cfi_startproc
    lock addl       $1, (%rdi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: I see it now. g++ simply failed to inline the function for fetch_add. The time savings was overhead for a function call.